# Error: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute, even if the attribute exist

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have the following code:

```
  company = Company.objects.filter(account=self.account).only('slug')
        if company:
            return redirect(reverse_lazy('company:detail_a', kwargs={'slug': company.slug}))
```

I get the error:

```
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'slug'
```

The `slug` attribute definitely exist(checked in model/database). I tried to access it like in a template.

So I tried with other attributes, 'name', because appears when I print the QuerySet.

So I think the QuerySet is not evaluated or something like that, but I don't know how to force to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter` will return a query set not a model object if you want a single object not a queryset try filter with first

```
  company = Company.objects.filter(account=self.account).only('slug').first()
  if company:
      return redirect(reverse_lazy('company:detail_a', kwargs={'slug': company.slug}))
```

OR

```
company = Company.objects.only('slug').get(account=self.account)
  if company:
      return redirect(reverse_lazy('company:detail_a', kwargs={'slug': company.slug}))
```

Answer (score 3):

A QuerySet is a collection of instances. The collection doesn't have any of those attributes; only the individual instances do.

If you want to get an individual instance, use `get` instead of `filter`.

Answer (score 0):

**if you try to use it on a detail-page try this**:

```
 <a href="{{ object.get_add_to_cart_url }}" class="cart-btn">Add to cart</a>
```

**instead of**:

```
    <a href="{{ item.get_add_to_cart_url }}" class="cart-btn">Add to cart</a>
```